# Xamarin Evolve - Errors on compilation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I just downloaded the `XamarinEvolve` project from `GitHub` and when trying to compile it on `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015` I got lot of errors as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Lot of these errors are related with the `Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)`.

As you can see on the image above I downloaded the DLL from:

> https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices-gcm

and added it to the project. But I think I'm still doing something wrong.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the project and build it on my machine. I have two issues with the project.

- The first one is that need to have Android API 24. So, install it from Android SDK Manager.
- The second one regarding the GCM. Please delete the GCM from your project using **Package Manager Console** using `Uninstall-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm`. Then try reinstalling it using `Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm -Version 29.0.0.2`
- Clean, And Build.